# Expected response code 354 but got code "503"

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I am trying to create a Contact Us Form in a Laravel Project but ran into the following error and would like to know how to solve this.

> Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error: 503-"Your IP: 202.133.88.147 : Your domain gmail.com is not allowed in header 503-From" 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA "

The following is my **.ENV** file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME=support@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**Controller**

```
  public function contactus()
    {
        return view('contactus');
    }

    public function sendContactMail(Request $request)
    {
        Mail::to('support@mydomain.com')->send(new ContactUs($request));
        Session::flash('success','Message Sent Successfully!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**ContactUs.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactUs extends Mailable
{
    protected $contactdata;
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $this->contactdata = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->contactdata->email)
                    ->subject($this->contactdata->subject)
                    ->with([
                        'message'   =>  $this->contactdata->message,
                        'fullname'  =>  $this->contactdata->first_name.' '.$this->contactdata->last_name
                    ])
                    ->markdown('emails.contactus');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you double check the smtp port? The default one without encryption is 25

Comment: You're not allowed to send mail from an @gmail account from anything other than gmail.

Comment: @I.Antonov:  The error "Error 503: Valid RCPT command must precede DATA" usually happens when your SMTP (outgoing mail) connection was not properly authenticated by your email server. As @mdexp put it, you're probably setting your port number wrong. Also I think your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` setting should be `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=` instead of `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`.

Comment: @mdexp i tried smtp port 25, still same result.

Comment: @KoalaYeung tried MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null, same result

Comment: @I-Antonov: Did you try `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung my mistake, i tried `MAIL_ENCRYPTION= ` also. same result.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the valid SMTP config from your vendor? Can you show us?

Comment: Sorry, missed the point that you're sending email through Gmail. I think you need to reference [their documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) about encryption and port. You'll probably need to use `587` port with `tls` encryption. Also your account needs to be either a Gmail account or a [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com) email account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199743/discussion-between-i-antonov-and-koala-yeung).

Answer (score 13):

I solved this by replacing *Global "From" Address* in mail.php file to the same input at .env for `MAIL_USERNAME=` .

Answer (score 4):

From the error message, you're probably sending email through Gmail's SMTP service.

Your `.env` should look like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also you need to make sure:

1. Your domain `mydomain.com` is properly setup to use [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/)'s Gmail. You cannot setup Gmail's SMTP to send email of domains that are not in GSuite nor is a Gmail account.
2. If your account has [2-step-verificaton](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) enabled, you'd need an [App Password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en) for SMTP login.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I fixed the issue by assigning **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS** equal to **MAIL_USERNAME**. I don't know the explanation though.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=hello@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/503-sender-verify-failed-503-valid-rcpt-command-must-precede-data):

> After correctly setting up your SMTP or mail driver of choice. Sending a mail with a "mail-from" different from your hostname e.g "no-reply@differenthost.com" and your hostname is yourhost.com The mail will always go through, **however, sending a mail with a "mail-from" as such: "no-reply@yourhost.com" which is possibly different from your .env mail authentication i.e "MAIL_USERNAME" : This will throw an error if that mail account hasn't been set up on your hosted server or c-panel.**

My .env file had:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=foo@bar.com
```

But my code had:

```
public function build()
{
    return
      $this
        ->from('myaddress@sometherdomain.com')
        ->view('emails.clientNotification');
}
```

This fixed it:

```
public function build()
{
    return
      $this
        ->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'))
        ->view('emails.clientNotification');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the mail addres in config/mail.php file. Change it to something other than gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *config/mail.php* and makes sure all the variables are correctly defined in you .env file. For example if you *mail.php* has the code:

```
    'from' => [
         'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
         'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],
```

and the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is not defined in .env then it may give such an error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred because of a case-sensitive issue of a variable in the **env** file.

```
The names of environment variables are case-sensitive.
```

In my `.env` file I have a variable, `mail_username=*******` but in the `mail.php` file `mail_username` variable accessed in `uppercase` like this `'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME')`. That's why this error occurred.

```
By convention, environment variables are in uppercase.
```

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR - Sending mail to an email that does not exist on your domain could cause the error.

None of the above is related to my own case. The cause of my problem was that I was sending an email to internal an account that does not exist.

my env configuration used `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@domain.com` and am trying to send mail to `user@domain.com` that does not exist.

So when I remove the user with `user@domain.com` from the list, the error gets fixed

Answer (score 0):

i Had the same problem and i fixed the error.

1. what you have to do is use the same email set up by your server. for example you cant user from gmail coz gmail isn't your domain on your server.

- you have to define like so.

  ```
     public function build()


  {
    return $this->from('support@mydomain.com')}
  ```

-or
2. you can remove the (from) everywhere you put it and just add this (MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=upport@mydomain.com) to you .env file and then edit your config/mail.php Like So

```
  'from' => [
     'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
     'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears if you are using `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun` on a 7.x Laravel and below. Use `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` until you upgrade.